# How to deal with Dynamic Link URL?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a form to register users, working just fine, using    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword.

But I want to send a verification link and the Firebase help show me that I had to use `actionCodeSettings`.

But the documentention is far from being helpfull.

Can you guys and gals help me with some advices?

```
var actionCodeSettings = {
   url: 'https://newagent-48d6b.firebaseapp.com/__/?email=' + firebase.auth().emailUser,
   iOS: {
      bundleId: 'com.example.ios'
   },
   android: {
      packageName: 'com.example.android',
      installApp: true,
      minimumVersion: '12'
   },
   handleCodeInApp: true,
      dynamicLinkDomain: "example.page.link"
   };

firebase.auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail(emailUser, actionCodeSettings)
   .then(function() {
      window.localStorage.setItem('emailForSignIn', emailUser);
      console.log("rocks")
    })
   .catch(function(error) {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log(errorCode + errorMessage);
   });
```

Console log:
auth/invalid-dynamic-link-domainThe provided dynamic link domain is not configured or authorized for the current project.

Many in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that the domain for dynamic links you are using is not authorized, you can authorize domains from the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) - Authentication -> Sign in method

```
bundleId: 'com.example.ios'
packageName: 'com.example.android',
dynamicLinkDomain: "example.page.link"
```

This is just a sample data you still need to fill your actual app settings here, getting the `auth/invalid-dynamic-link-domain` means that you've probably left `dynamicLinkDomain: "example.page.link"` the way it is

1. `dynamicLinkDomain` is not a required field so you can just remove that
2. You still need to enable dynamic links from the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/). this will create a default domain an it should be whitelisted automatically
3. You still need to whitelist any domains you are using in the `url`. `*.firebaseapp.com` should be already whitelisted for you. To allow domains go to the Authentication page from the Firebase console

To be able to handle the code in the app (`handleCodeInApp: true`) there are additional project specific configuration